# how to check string contains any word from dataframe colum

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to find pandas column all the cell value to particular string how do I check it?

there is one dataframe and one string, want to search entire df column into string, it should return matching elements from column

looking for solution like in MySQL

```
select * from table where "string" like CONCAT('%',columnname,'%')
```

**Dataframe:**

```
    area                   office_type
0        c d a (o)         S.O
1    dr.b.a. chowk         S.O
2   ghorpuri bazar         S.O
3     n.w. college         S.O
4  pune cantt east         S.O
5             pune         H.O
6   pune new bazar         S.O
7  sachapir street         S.O
```

**Code:**

```
tmp_df=my_df_main[my_df_main['area'].str.contains("asasa sdsd sachapir street sdsds ffff")]
```

in above example "sachapir street" is there is pandas column in area and also it is there in string, it should return "sachapir street" for matching word.

I know it should be like a reverse I tried my code like

```
tmp_df=my_df_main["asasa sdsd sachapir street sdsds ffff".str.contains(my_df_main['area'])]
```

any idea how to do that?

Comment: when you say any word in the column do you mean any word separated by spaces in each string or the whole string in each row the column?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: whatever matches in both the place. eg. here "sachapir street" maches bothe the place so it should be output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did this using "import pandasql as ps"

```
query = "SELECT area,office_type FROM my_df_main where 'asasa sdsd sachapir street sdsds ffff' like '%'||area||'%'"
tmp_df = ps.sqldf(query, locals())
```

Comment: Is possible see data distingush pairs vs single words?

Comment: yes, distingush pairs is possible,  it returns "sachapir street" as output as expected. padassql is exactly replica of MySQL, so you can write MySQL queries in padas.

Comment: So if change `c d a (o)` to `another street` is is not filtered? Only `sachapir street` ?

Comment: Or if change `dr.b.a. chowk` to `sachapir`  not filtered, because `sachapir street` ?